# django.db.utils.IntegrityError in Custom UserModel

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-users, django-rest-auth

Custom User Model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True,max_length=75)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

On running `./manage.py migrate`, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
```

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` on mysql shows:

```
2015-07-12 19:29:25 133f4a000 Error in foreign key constraint of table edutraffic/#sql-55ea_17a:
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`):
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`id`)
```

So, I deleted the complete database and recreated it, still getting the same error.

`settings.py` file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

    'users',
)
```

Comment: You have `managed = False`, which means that Django will not create the table. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: Silly mistake..Your suggestion worked !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set [`managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#managed) to `False`, which means that Django will not create the table. Either remove that line, or create the table manually.